# How to append more text into UILabel in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel

I want to append more text behind UILabel in iOS.

In other languages, we can add following as:

```
String s += textBox.text;
```

We can use (+=) sign in others languages.

In Objective-C , I don't know how to add into label.

Please help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try out this:

```
label.text = [label.text stringByAppendingString:@"your text"];
```

This should help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", label.text, @"your text to append"];
```

Answer (score 3):

when you have a string which will change constantly,i advice you to use NSMutableString

    `NSMutableString *str=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"aaaaaa"];
    [str appendString:@"bbbbbb"];`

Answer (score 2):

I am used like below lines,

```
label.text = "My Text"
label.text = label.text! + " appended text"
```